# Absolute imports - module not found

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import

I'm trying to organize my scripts in a way I can use absolute imports, without appending to `sys.path`, making it as easy to use in different computers as possible without problems. I have read and I understand absolute paths are the most appropriate way to do this.

My folder structure looks something like:

```
main/
  __init__.py
  tools/
    __init__.py
    script1.py
  base/
    __init__.py
    script2.py
```

I have been trying to do `from main.tools.script1 import Foo` in file `main/base/script2.py` and I still get the error `ImportError: No module named main.tools.script1`.

If is print `sys.path`, the first item is `main/base/`. 
If I run python on a terminal from main, I can import `tools.script1`, but cannot write `main.tools.script1`.

I have read other posts, but this is still really not clear for me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
MyNiceProgram-1.0/
    setup.py
    README
    LICENSE
    bin/ 
        myniceprogram.py # main entry point
    myniceprogram/
        __init__.py
        tools/
            __init__.py
            script1.py
        base
            __init__.py
            script2.py
```

Then you use:

```
from myniceprogram.tools import script1
from myniceprogram.base import script2
```

**Don't**

- Name your main package `main` - it should be treated as a global package so the name should be descriptive. If you want to have a package named `main` put it inside `myniceprogram.main`
- Execute scripts inside your package. Your main script should be **outside** the package for absolute import to work. Otherwise you can end up having two copies of the same script, imported absolutely and relatively.

Comment: Still with this structure my module `myniceprogram.tools.script1` cannot be found. If I run python on the command line from `MyNiceProgram-1.0/` and try to import the module from there it does work, but not if I do `python  myniceprogram/tools/script1.py` from the same location.

Comment: @cap as I said in the "Don't" part, you should not execute scripts that are inside your package. Put your executable scripts (entry points) outside the package, even if they are only `from myniceprogram/tools/script1 import main; main()`

Comment: In that case writing `from myniceprogram.tools.script1 import main` inside `bin/myniceprogram.py` should work right?, but it still says module not found. Maybe there's something fundamental I'm not seeing. Could it be the version of python? 2.7 as the tag says.

Comment: @cap the `bin/` folder is for scripts that should be installed with your package. When you run `python setup.py install` your package gets installed to `site-packages` and the contents of `bin` go to `Scripts` folder. When your package is installed, importing it from anywhere will work. If you want the code to work without installing the package with `setup.py` then the script must be in the root folder (where `setup.py` is) and not inside `bin`

Comment: @cap in other words, should `myniceprogram` be **installed**, then the script can be anywhere you want

Comment: Thank you! It makes much more sense now.